# PHP+MYSQL encoding, utf8_polish_ci

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Hello i have problem with encoding in my script. 
My connect function looks like:

```
function connect()
{
    $conn = mysql_connect('192.168.1.127', 'mason_frik', 'difficultpassword');
    if (!$conn) 
    {
        die('Nie można się połaczyć!');
    }
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'; COLLATE='utf8_polish_ci';");
    mysql_query("SET character_set_client = 'utf8'");
    mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8'");
    mysql_query("SET character_set_connection = 'utf8'");
    mysql_select_db('mason_konkursy');
}
```

In my database i'm using utf8_polish_ci everywhere.
In my script i'm getting something from other page and i need to search it in my db like this:
//this function is parsing other page and get innertext of SPAN.

```
$question = GetSpanData($FirstQuestion, "dnn_ctr1975_ViewContestsContestNew_dc_question_lblQuestion");



$wyn = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM questions WHERE question="'.$question.'"'); 
$wynik = mysql_fetch_array($wyn, MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

Result is bool(false).
When i copy query to my phpmyadmin and paste to sql it is working, but from my script it didn't.
Can You help me?

Comment: As stated in [the introduction](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) to the PHP manual chapter on the `mysql_*` functions: *This extension is not recommended for writing new code. Instead, either the [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.*

Comment: Can you tell what this code returns: `echo 'SELECT * FROM questions WHERE question="'.$question.'"';` ?

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'; COLLATE='utf8_polish_ci';");
```

The [correct syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-connection.html) is:

```
SET NAMES 'charset_name' COLLATE 'collation_name'
```

In your case, the code would the be:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_polish_ci';");
```

And read the first comment posted by eggyal: mysql_* functions should not be used anymore, they are deprecated and will be removed from PHP in a future version.

You may be missing a call to mysql_real_escape_string in this line of code (it is not possible for me to be sure, it depends what the function `GetSpanData` exactly does):

```
mysql_query('SELECT * FROM questions WHERE question="'.$question.'"');
```

to escape the data properly, you must use the [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) function:

```
mysql_query('SELECT * FROM questions WHERE question="'.mysql_real_escape_string($question).'"');
```

Comment: I have changed it to MYSQLI:

    $conn = mysqli_connect('192.168.1.127', 'mason_frik', 'difficultpassword','mason_konkursy');
    $conn->query("SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_polish_ci'");

    $wyn = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM pytania WHERE pytanie="'.$pytanie.'"'); 
    $wynik = mysqli_fetch_assoc($wyn);
    $odp = $wynik['odp'];


But it is no working. Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Still bool(false) results. I don't know what i need to do.

Comment: Before trying to update your code with mysqli functions, try my answer. If my answer doesn't work, check the result of `mysql_error()` after each call to `mysql_query()`. It probably returns an error message somewhere. When the code properly works with mysql_* functions, then you may change it to work with mysqli_* functions.